# Eclipse throws "Unexpected Version: 0" Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been developing a minecraft mod, and ever since Eclipse crashed it gives me this error:

```
Could not read metadata for    
'C:\Users\schwa\Desktop\Mod\eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.root\.indexes\properties.index'. 
Unexpected version: 0.
```

I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably the eclipse project file became corrupted. Try to delete the eclipse project file/folder and import the project again

Answer (score 1):

Simple Refresh of the project will fix it. Right click project and select refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Force update your project. This might solve the issue.

In eclipse select the project -> right click -> maven -> update project -> select force update of snapshots/Releases checkbox -> click OK.